# Search input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, token

I'm using [bootstrap-tokenfield](http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/)

I'm using tokenfield in search bar, and have one small problem, lets say I search: *searchtag1*, *searchtag2* and after I click on search and page loads my search resuts in search input there is no *searchtag1*, *searchtag2*

I want tags that I search for stay in input box on search page also, how to accomplish this?

I'm using default bootstrap form

```html
<div class="search">
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" action="{{ url('sonata_search') }}" method="GET">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="tags" class="form-control tokenfield" name="search" value="tag, tag2" placeholder="Search" type="text"  />
            <button type="submit" id="sonata_search_submit" class="btnbtn-default">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show your full html form and javascript code?

Comment: my whole seach html is here now, im working on symfony project(front part), this integrate on symfony search, so this is what i have available for now, is there any way to cache my searched word and show on result page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`, cookies or you can submit form with AJAX and just show submitted tags in input field on ajax success with no need for page reload.

Here is example with `sessionStorage`:

```
$(function() {
    // on form submit set tags in sessionStorage
    $('form').on('submit', function() {
        var tagsValue = $('#tags').val();
        sessionStorage.setItem('tags', tagsValue);
    });
    // if tags exist in sessionStorage set them as value in input field
    var tagsSession = sessionStorage.getItem('tags');
    if (tagsSession != null){
        $('#tags').val(tagsSession);
    }
    $('#tags').tokenfield();
});
```

Comment: what doesn't work? do you get any errors in console? did you check if tags are saved in sessionStorage? it works fine for me so you probably implemented it wrong.

Comment: N erors, and in sessionStorage in inspector there is new Value i added, but it doesnt show in input field

Comment: it's hard for me to help when I can't reproduce your issue. try to test it... do `console.log` of `tagsSession` inside `if` etc.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP protocol, and therefore web servers are **[stateless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol)**. Cookies and session variables are the easiest ways to get around that and implement cross-page state.

But there is a better way. It looks like you are using a *laravel* and *blade*, but this approach will work in generally the same fashion for any web server / library.

What you need to do is [send the tags](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#passing-data-to-views) to the search "results" page. In the template you need to figure out some way to re-create the tags with the data you got back from the server.